# SSH HTTP tunneling on OS X

Tags: macos, ssh, tunnel, http

On Windows I use PuTTY to tunnel to my home server and tell Firefox to use PuTTY as a proxy. How would I accomplish something similar on my Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MacOSX ssh client is based off OpenSSH.

> ssh -D `<port number>` **username@remote.host**

You want the `-D` flag for dynamic application-level port forwarding.

From the man-page - http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ssh.1.html

> Specifies a local "dynamic" application-level port forwarding.
>    This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local
>    side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a
>    connection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over
>    the secure channel, and the application protocol is then used to
>    determine where to connect to from the remote machine.  Currently
>    the SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 protocols are supported, and ssh will act
>    as a SOCKS server.  Only root can forward privileged ports.
>    Dynamic port forwardings can also be specified in the configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to access just a single service, for example some web frontend use:

```
ssh -L <local port>:<host>:<remote port> username@remote.host
```

You can also put all this in your .ssh/config file, like this:

```
Host <nickname>
 HostName <remote.host>
 User <username>
 LocalForward <localport> <host>:<remoteport>
```

You can also specify multiple LocalForward lines if you have multiple servers/services to connect to, or use the dynamic application-level port forwarding as explained per Darren Hall.